# golang gorilla/session got nil value while checking session

Tags: go, gorilla

I have imported packages as

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

    //CORS
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "github.com/justinas/alice"  
)
```

and defined store and main method as follow

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("something-very-secret")) 

const My_UI="http://localhost:3000"

func init() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   3600 * 1, // 1 hour
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}

var router = mux.NewRouter() //MUX Handeler

//MAIN Function

func main() {
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{My_UI},
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/submitted",Login)
    router.HandleFunc("/check",GetSession)
    http.Handle("/", router)

    chain := alice.New(c.Handler).Then(router) //CORS enable

    fmt.Println("server started at port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", chain)
}
```

In my method I’ve created and set session value as describe in gorilla doc

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {         
    fmt.Println("In login----------->")
    sess := GetCon()                              //get connection session
    defer sess.Close()                           //close session    
    c := sess.DB("mydb").C("users")      //collection-> select db table

    session1, _ := store.Get(r, "loginSession")  //login session

    //parse json data  
    form := LoginUser{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&form)
    if err !=nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //get query data
    var result []Person

    errc1 := c.Find(bson.M{"email":form.Email,"password":form.Password}).All(&result)

    if errc1 != nil {
        js, err2 := json.Marshal("false")
        if err2 != nil{return}
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(js)     
    } else {
        if len(result)==0 {
            if err2 != nil {
                return
            }
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(js) 
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Success")  
            session1.Values["foo"] = "bar"  
            session1.Save(r, w) 
            fmt.Println("saved",session1)
            js, err2 := json.Marshal(&result[0].Id)
            if err2 != nil {return}
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(js) 
        }       
    }   
}
```

Now if i want to get this session value in another method i got nil every time. don't know what goes wrong in my code.

```
func GetSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session1, _ := store.Get(r, "loginSession")
    fmt.Println("Session in SessionHandler",session1)

    if session.Values["foo"] == nil {
        fmt.Println("not found",session.Values["foo"]))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("value",session.Values["foo"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check for errors? Looks like you are ignoring them in your example code. If I had to guess, I'd say you already have written to `http.ResponseWriter` before saving the session (headers sent).

Comment: yes, I’ve checked it. got nil value ->" not found <nil>" while checking condition for session in GetSession() method.

Comment: according to doc (gorilla) for saving any session we've to write session.Save(r, w).. and for multiple session they have mention sessions.Save(r,w).

Comment: Correct — but you need to do this BEFORE you render a template or write any kind of response. Can you post the full `Login` function in your code?

Comment: I'm not rendering any templates from golang. i've used angularJS for that. golang only handles json request from angular, process that request and give responce back to angular.

Comment: Rendering has nothing to do with it. If you are doing output in your HTTP body before you are setting the headers (where the cookie will be set), it won't work.

Comment: Nothing against alice nor rs/cors. But middlewares are not a pain in go as well as cors.

Comment: Does your session cookie name use spaces? If so, remove all spaces and try again. (See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9758 ).

Answer (score 2):

You got a mistake at your GetSession function. Please change `session` variable to `session1`

Also to check if session value is present better do it this way:

```
session, err := store.Get(r, ssid)
    if err == nil {
        if value, ok := session.Values["foo"].(string); ok {
            session_data = value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what value you what to get, but I assume you want a string value. I wrote simple `func GetFoo()` to get string value from `session1.Values["foo"]`.

Full example below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/justinas/alice"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("something-very-secret"))

const My_UI = "http://localhost:3000"

var router = mux.NewRouter() //MUX Handeler

//MAIN Function
func init() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   3600 * 1, // 1 hour
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}

func main() {
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{My_UI},
    })
    router.HandleFunc("/login", Login)
    router.HandleFunc("/check", GetSession)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    chain := alice.New(c.Handler).Then(router) //CORS enable
    fmt.Println("server started at port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", chain)
}

func GetFoo(f interface{}) string {
    if f != nil {
        if foo, ok := f.(string); ok {
            return foo
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func GetSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session1, _ := store.Get(r, "loginSession")
    foo := GetFoo(session1.Values["foo"])
    if foo == "" {
        fmt.Println("Foo is not set! Login to set value.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Foo Value:", foo, ".")
    }
}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Save Foo
    session1, _ := store.Get(r, "loginSession")
    session1.Values["foo"] = "bar"
    session1.Save(r, w)
}
```